# Verwendung von Personalpronomen

Tags: usage, grammaticality

Im folgenden Satz möchte ich Personalpronomen benutzen.

> Ich habe Ihnen die Kamera geschickt.
>   Bitte reparieren Sie sie und schicken **Sie sie mir** zurück.

Ist diese Anwendung richtig? Ich bin mir nicht ganz sicher, denn es klingt irgendwie merkwürdig.

Answer (score 5):

Ja, die Anwendung ist richtig.

Im Deutschen kommen solche Wiederholungen hin und wieder vor. Ein anderes Beispiel:

> Das ist Frau Müller, *die die* Ärztin kennt.

Comment: Im Beispiel aus der Frage stehen jeweils zwei Pronomen hintereinander. In deinem Beispiel folgt auf ein Relativpronomen aber ein Artikel.

Comment: Ja und? Beim Sprechen denkst du nicht darüber nach, sondern wunderst du dich, ob "die die" oder "Sie sie" korrekt sind.

Comment: Oder: Die, die die Ärztin kennt, ist frau Müller ;)

Answer (score 2):

Ja, das ist vollkommen korrekt.

Die beiden großgeschriebenen *Sie* werden von manchen Germanisten übrigens nicht als Personalpronomen, sondern als Anredepronomen klassifiziert. Die beiden kleingeschriebenen »sie« sind Demonstrativpronomen.

Comment: Die kleingeschriebenen 'sie' sind durchaus **Personalpronomen**. Demonstrativpronomen wären an diesen Stellen 'diese' oder (etwas informeller) 'die'.